# How to pull List View items into Excel?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have been stuck on this issue for a a day or so and need some help. In my application, I have some data in a listview, which is

```
 public void OnHostPing(HostPinger host)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new OnPingDelegate(OnHostPing), new object[] { host });
            return;
        }

        lock (_table)
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)_table[host.ID];
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.SubItems[0].Text = host.HostIP.ToString();
                item.SubItems[1].Text = host.HostName;
                item.SubItems[2].Text = host.HostDescription;

                item.SubItems[3].Text = host.StatusName;

                item.SubItems[4].Text = host.SentPackets.ToString();

                item.SubItems[5].Text = host.ReceivedPackets.ToString();
                item.SubItems[6].Text = PercentToString(host.ReceivedPacketsPercent);

                item.SubItems[7].Text = host.LostPackets.ToString();
                item.SubItems[8].Text = PercentToString(host.LostPacketsPercent);

                item.SubItems[9].Text = host.LastPacketLost ? "Yes" : "No";

                item.SubItems[10].Text = host.ConsecutivePacketsLost.ToString();
                item.SubItems[11].Text = host.MaxConsecutivePacketsLost.ToString();

                item.SubItems[12].Text = host.RecentlyReceivedPackets.ToString();
                item.SubItems[13].Text = PercentToString(host.RecentlyReceivedPacketsPercent);

                item.SubItems[14].Text = host.RecentlyLostPackets.ToString();
                item.SubItems[15].Text = PercentToString(host.RecentlyLostPacketsPercent);

                item.SubItems[16].Text = host.CurrentResponseTime.ToString();
                item.SubItems[17].Text = host.AverageResponseTime.ToString("F");

                item.SubItems[18].Text = host.MinResponseTime.ToString();
                item.SubItems[19].Text = host.MaxResponseTime.ToString();

                item.SubItems[20].Text = DurationToString(host.CurrentStatusDuration);

                item.SubItems[21].Text = DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Alive));
                item.SubItems[22].Text = DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Dead));
                item.SubItems[23].Text = DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.DnsError));
                item.SubItems[24].Text = DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Unknown));

                item.SubItems[25].Text = PercentToString(host.HostAvailability);

                item.SubItems[26].Text = DurationToString(host.TotalTestDuration);
                item.SubItems[27].Text = DurationToString(host.CurrentTestDuration);
            }
            else
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] 
                { 
                    host.HostIP.ToString(), host.HostName, host.HostDescription,
                    host.StatusName,
                    host.SentPackets.ToString(),
                    host.ReceivedPackets.ToString(), PercentToString(host.ReceivedPacketsPercent),
                    host.LostPackets.ToString(), PercentToString(host.LostPacketsPercent),
                    host.LastPacketLost ? "Yes" : "No",
                    host.ConsecutivePacketsLost.ToString(), host.MaxConsecutivePacketsLost.ToString(),
                    host.RecentlyReceivedPackets.ToString(), PercentToString(host.RecentlyReceivedPacketsPercent),
                    host.RecentlyLostPackets.ToString(), PercentToString(host.RecentlyLostPacketsPercent),
                    host.CurrentResponseTime.ToString(), host.AverageResponseTime.ToString("F"),
                    host.MinResponseTime.ToString(), host.MaxResponseTime.ToString(),
                    DurationToString(host.CurrentStatusDuration),
                    DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Alive)),
                    DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Dead)),
                    DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.DnsError)),
                    DurationToString(host.GetStatusDuration(HostStatus.Unknown)),
                    PercentToString(host.HostAvailability),
                    DurationToString(host.TotalTestDuration),
                    DurationToString(host.CurrentTestDuration)
                });
```

What I can't seem to figure out is, how to get that data exported to Excel? I am able to export static data to Excel with this code

```
  public static string RunSample1(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
        {

            if (!outputDir.Exists) throw new Exception("outputDir does not exist!");
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample1.xlsx");
            if (newFile.Exists)
            {
                newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
                newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\sample1.xlsx");
            }
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Current Devices");
                //Add the headers
                //worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Product";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Quantity";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Price";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Value";

                //Add some items...
                worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 12001;
                worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nails";
                worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 37;
                worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 3.99;
```

What I can't figure out is how to get those listview items in to the spreadsheet cells instead of static data. ListViewItems doesn't seem to yield the properties I would expect. Can someone help me out a bit here?

Comment: Since you use a listviewitem, to be able to get properties from it you'll have to store a copy of your object in ListviewItem.tag. Then once you are ready to put data in Excel, you cast the current listviewitem.tag to a Hostpinger object and it will have the properties you expect. ie: something like item.tag = host   then later, Hostpinger foobar = (Hostpinger)item.tag

Comment: so after each item.subitem I would need to create an item.tag = hostip or whatever the subitem is?

Comment: No just the initial item. It's item.tag, not item.subitem[].tag. Then you'd do something like worksheet.Cells["A2"].value = foobar.Hostname; Basically ListViewItem is its own type and the only way to keep the object for later use is to use .Tag. By the way, I won't do so, but other posters might try to convince you that ListViewItem is probably not the right control for your task.

Comment: Following your example, Im getting that item doesnt exist in the current context. I tried using this directly before the cell population

     ------- HostPinger myTag = (HostPinger)item.tag;

It doesnt like item in that context for some reason.

Comment: I never did get this to work. I actually going to go another route and use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to create the workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel instead of trying to use the EPPlus solution.